# Can i get text insted of numbers in the output?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

```
package java_noob;


public class Java_noob {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create 2-dimensional array.
        int[][] values = new int[4][4];

        // Assign three elements in it.
        values[0][0] = 1;
        values[1][1] = 2;
        values[3][2] = 3;

        // Loop over top-level arrays.
        for (int[] sub: values) {
            // Loop and display sub-arrays.
            for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
                System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output is

1 0 0 0

0 2 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 3 0

how do i get an array with text instead of numbers?
 I tried to change the numbered  values to text, but it doesn`t work. Am i using the wrong type of array? ( one dimentional, multi- dimentional)

Comment: Should the array be of type string? Is that your need?

Comment: why are you using a 2-D array?

Answer (score 1):

To print or get the values as a String:

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(sub[x]) + " ");
```

To have an array of Strings

```
String[][] values = new String[4][4];
values[0][0] = "1";
values[1][1] = "2";
values[3][2] = "3";
// the other fields will not be "0" but edit: null
```

Comment: it should be print not println

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama fixed ty

Comment: Wow, i really overlooked that part. wel it works now, thanks.

Comment: The other fields will be null, not an empty string (will print as `null`).

Comment: @OleV.V. fixed ty

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an array that contains the characters you'd like to be able to use. then you'd have to call them in the index. not sure if that will help but its suggestion. good luck!